# Not getting android push notification messages from gcm

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an android application with push notification using GCM (step by step: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)  but not all devices getting notifications from GCM server.

I debugged it and I saw that my 3d-party server sends the message successfully.

When i send to my Galaxy-S4 device I get the notification but in my Galaxy-S2 i don't get.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver
        android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.freco" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".gcm.GcmIntentService" />
```

I think the other code its not necessary here because its works fine in Galaxy-S4.

What do you think is it ?

Comment: same problem with me.. can you suggest me what you did to receive notifications on S2?

Comment: after some days i got a block of message to the other devices. since then everything worked.

Comment: Hi friend, 
manifest is fine.
can you post class service + class receiver for handling GCM

Answer (score 1):

What's the package of your app, com.freco (as defined in the category of the broadcast receiver) or com.example.gcm (as defined in your permissions)?

You should use the package name of your app in both places. For some reason, this mismatch only causes problems in older Android versions. Newer versions work either way.

Comment: What if I marked it any application allowed?while declaring the key?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a copy paste error. In your manifest, change `com.example` to your actual package name